# How to pass values from array to array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Can I pass values from one array to another array? Here is an example:

```
@a = [{:id => '1', :name => 'abcd'}, {:id => '2', :name => "asadad"}, ...]
@b = [0, 1]
```

I want to pass values from `@a` to `@b` like this:

```
@b[0] = {:id => '1', :name => 'abcd'}
...
@b[1] = {:id => '2', :name => 'asadad'}
```

Can I do that and how can I do that?

Comment: Does `[0,1]` refer to indices in `@a`?

Comment: You want  to move all values from @a to @b or just some specific ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not clear what you are doing, but it looks like this:

```
@b = @a.values_at(*@b)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does the `*` do. Does it have any relation with the pointers or so.

Comment: Yeah!!That's what I want to do, thanks you so much :)

Comment: @Deep it expands the array elements to an argument list. `values_at(*[1,2,3])` becomes `values_at(1,2,3)`